# Selectively include text labels on graph

Tags: r, graph, plot, label

I plot the following data frame (`x`):

```
  Position     S1     S2     S3     S4
1       53 0.0000 0.5000 0.0000 0.2000
2       54 0.2000 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000
3       55 0.0000 0.5000 0.1000 0.0000
4       56 0.0000 0.0000 0.1000 0.4000
5       57 0.2000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
6       58 0.0000 0.0000 0.2000 0.0000
7       59 0.3000 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000
8       60 0.0000 0.4000 0.0000 0.6000
9       61 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.5000
10      62 0.0000 0.0000 0.1000 0.6000
```

and add text using

```
plot(x$S1, type="h")
text(x$S1)
```

However, I only want text for values in the table above a threshold. So I do the following:

```
plot(x$S1, type="h")
y = x$S1
y[y<0.2] = NA
text(y)
```

This works as I would like it to. However, ideally, I would like the x-axis values to be `x$Position`, rather than just incrementing from 1. I can plot this with:

```
plot(x$Position, x$S1, type="h")
```

but the text labels still show the incrementing values, not the values of `x$Position`. I have tried a number of approaches to solve this, but have not had success.

**How can I include `x$Position` values as text on the graph, but only for `x$S1` values above a threshold?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?:

```
plot(x$Position, x$S1, type="h")
text(x$Position,y,labels=x$Position)
```